# I have multiple columns in csv. How do I match row values to a reference column using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a `csv` file with 367 columns. The first column has 15 unique values, and each subsequent column has some subset of those 15 values. No unique value is ever found more than once in a column. Each column is sorted. How do I get the rows to line up? My end goal is to make a presence/absence heat map, but I need to get the data matrix in the right format first, which I am struggling with.

Here is a small example of the type of data I have:

```
1,2,1,2
2,3,2,5
3,4,3,
4,,5,
5,,,
```

I need the rows to match the reference but stay in the same column like so:

```
1,,1,
2,2,2,2
3,3,3,
4,4,,
5,,5,5
```

My thought was to use the `pandas` library, but I could not figure out how to approach this problem, as I am very new to using python. I am using python2.7.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is definitely solvable via `pandas`:

**Code:**

```
# Create the sample data into a data frame
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(u"""
    1,2,1,2
    2,3,2,5
    3,4,3,
    4,,5,
    5,,,"""), header=None, skip_blank_lines=1).fillna(0)
for column in df:
    df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='integer')

# set the first column as an index
df = df.set_index([0])

# create a frame which we will build up 
results = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

# add each column to the datafarme indicating if the desired value is present
for col in df.columns:
    results[col] = df.index.isin(df[col])

# output the dataframe in the desired format
for idx, row in results.iterrows():
    result = '%s,%s' % (idx, ','.join(str(idx) if x else ''
                                      for x in row.values))
    print(result)
```

**Results:**

```
1,,1,
2,2,2,2
3,3,3,
4,4,,
5,,5,5
```

**How does it work?:**

Pandas can be little daunting when first approached, even for someone who knows python well, so I will try to walk through this.  And I encourage you to do what you need to get over the learning curve, because `pandas` is ridiculously powerful for this sort of data manipulation.

**Get the data into a frame:**

This first bit of code does nothing but get your sample data into a `pandas.DataFrame`.  Your data format was not specified so I will assume, that you can get it into a frame, or if you can not get it into a frame, will ask another question here on SO about getting the data into a frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(u"""
    1,2,1,2
    2,3,2,5
    3,4,3,
    4,,5,
    5,,,"""), header=None, skip_blank_lines=1).fillna(0)
for column in df:
    df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='integer')    

# set the first column as an index
df = df.set_index([0])
```

**Build a result frame:**

Start with a result frame that is just the index

```
# create a frame which we will build up 
results = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
```

For each column in the source data, see if the value is in the index

```
# add each column to the dataframe indicating if the desired value is present
for col in df.columns:
    results[col] = df.index.isin(df[col])
```

That's it, with three lines of code, we have calculated our results.

**Output the results:**

Now iterate through each row, which contains booleans, and output the values in the desired format (as ints)

```
# output the dataframe in the desired format
for idx, row in results.iterrows():
    result = '%s,%s' % (idx, ','.join(str(idx) if x else ''
                                      for x in row.values))
    print(result)
```

This outputs the index value first, and then for each `True` value outputs the index again, and for `False` values outputs an empty string.

**Postscript:**

There are quite a few people here on SO who are way better at `pandas` than I am, but since you did not tag your question, with the `pandas` keyword, they likely did not notice this question.  But that allows me to take my cut at answering before they notice. The `pandas` keyword is very well covered for well formed questions, so I am pretty sure that if this answer is not optimum, someone else will come by and improve it.  So in the future, be sure to tag your question with `pandas` to get the best response.

Also, you mentioned that you were new python, so I will just put in a plug to make sure that you are using a good IDE.  I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), and it and other good IDEs can make working in python even more powerful, so I highly recommend them.